# Serializing POSIX threads using Mutex

Tags: c, multithreading, synchronization, posix

I am trying to make a program that creates 3 threads threa1 thread2 and thread3 thread1 prints thread1 5 times, thread2 prints thread2 5 times and thread3 prints thread3 5 times
I want to use mutexes to have this output

```
thread1
thread1
thread1
thread1
thread1
thread2
thread2
thread2
thread2
thread2
thread3
thread3
thread3
thread3
thread3
```

how can I do that ?

Comment: If the behavior you need is expressly serial why do you want to use multiple threads?

Comment: i know I dont actually need threads, but its a practicing assignment on mutexes

Comment: @MRezk: That's not really what mutexes are for. Mutexes are for protecting access to shared memory. What you want is to enforce a specific global ordering.

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define MAX_PRINT 5
#define MAX_THREAD 3

static pthread_mutex_t mThread[MAX_THREAD] = {PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER, PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER, PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER};

void * start_thread(void * arg)
{
    int thNb = *((int*)arg);
    int i = 0;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mThread[thNb]);

    for (i = 0; i < MAX_PRINT; i++) {
        fprintf(stdout, "thread%d\n", thNb);
    }

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mThread[thNb]);

    return NULL;
}


int main()
{
    pthread_t thread[MAX_THREAD];
    int arg[MAX_THREAD];
    int i = 0;

    printf("Init Mutex for all threads ...");
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_THREAD; i++) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mThread[i]);
    }
    printf("OK\n");

    printf("Creating threads ...");
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_THREAD; i++) {
        arg[i] = i;
        pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, &start_thread, &arg[i]);
    }
    printf("OK\n");

    printf("::::::::::::::::: OUTPUT THAT YOU WANT :::::::::::::::::::::: \n");
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_THREAD; i++)
    {
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mThread[i]);
        pthread_join(thread[i], NULL);
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Compile it using:

```
gcc -D_REENTRANT -lpthread main.c
```

Comment: IOW, you gave half an answer.

Comment: I know. The goal of the question is practicing, so I'm trying to not ruin this :)

Comment: That doesn't guarantee the order that the OP seems to be asking for. Then again, the OP seems pretty confused, so it's unclear what the right answer is.